# MS SQL Querying Tables Where Data may or may not exist

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Have not come across an exact use-case for what I'm trying to achieve on Stackoverflow so will explain it in the hopes someone can assist.

I have two tables, one contains a master activity list and the other contains who completed those activities.

Table A is the Activity Table. This is a distinct list of things that can be done.

```
ID  |  Activity
---------------------------
1   |  Change Oil
2   |  Change Airfilter
3   |  Change Brake Fluid
```

Table B is the Activity Log table. This tracks where people have done one of the above Activities. ActivityID links to ID on Table A.

```
ID  | ActivityID  | CompletedBy 
---------------------------------------
1   | 1           | john@auto.com
2   | 1           | sally@auto.com
3   | 3           | john@auto.com
```

What I am trying to produce is a list of all activities, but then only for a distinct person. I have tried multiple ways for this, but can only get the query to show where values exist in both tables.

My preferred output would be the following, where in the query i have asked to show me the full Activity list and also to show where John has completed anything. If there is no record in Table B for this activity, to show a blank value.

```
ID  | Activity            | CompletedBy
-------------------------------------------
1   | Change Oil          | john@auto.com
2   | Change Airfilter    | 
3   | Change Brake Fluid  | john@auto.com
```

Here is my current SQL Query in my attempt to work this one out, which right now the results only return ID 1 and 3 from that example above, where john actually has a record in Table B.

```
Select a.ID, a.Activity, b.CompletedBy
FROM ActivityList a
LEFT OUTER JOIN ActivityLog b
ON a.ID = b.ActivityID
Where CompletedBy = 'john@auto.com'
GROUP BY a.ID, a.Activity, b.CompletedBy
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the `CompletedBy` restriction into the join conditions you would not need the group by.

```
Select a.ID, a.Activity, b.CompletedBy
FROM ActivityList a
LEFT OUTER JOIN ActivityLog b
ON a.ID = b.ActivityID and b.CompletedBy = 'john@auto.com'
```

Comment: OP accepted other answer before I posted mine. Thanks for the feedback tho @GordonLinoff ;-)

Comment: Thanks bradbury9. This solution was the one that actually solved the issue for me. Appreciate the posting of this solution even after I had jumped the gun on selecting another one.

Answer (score 1):

Change your where clause to `Where CompletedBy = 'john@auto.com' or CompletedBy is null` so it matches on a text match or the case where the name does not exist at all. You can also use `isnull(` to convert the null value to a empty string if that is the behavior you are wanting.

```
Select a.ID, a.Activity, isnull(b.CompletedBy, '') as CompletedBy
FROM ActivityList a
LEFT OUTER JOIN ActivityLog b
ON a.ID = b.ActivityID
Where CompletedBy = 'john@auto.com' or b.CompletedBy is null
GROUP BY a.ID, a.Activity, b.CompletedBy
```

Comment: Thanks Scott!, glad it was something small to add and that I hadn't spent the last hour working thru various permutations of that query for nothing. Great work in helping me out. Cheers

Comment: Depending on the volume of data in `ActivityLog` and/or existing indexes this answer could have bad performance because of joining innecesary data.

Comment: @Stephen85 . . . This answer is not correct.  Activities completed by *another* person will be filtered out.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, and confirming that the query above seemed to have addressed the issue, but then clicking thru various names the query did not always return the full set of Activities. Confirming that bradbury9 offered up a solution that works better for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable table_A = new DataTable();
            table_A.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            table_A.Columns.Add("Activity", typeof(string));

            table_A.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Change Oil"});
            table_A.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Change Airfilter"});
            table_A.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Change Brake Fluid"});


            DataTable table_B = new DataTable();
            table_B.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            table_B.Columns.Add("ActivityID", typeof(string));
            table_B.Columns.Add("CompletedBy", typeof(string));

            table_B.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, "john@auto.com"});
            table_B.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 1, "sally@auto.com"});
            table_B.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 3, "john@auto.com"});

            var groups = (from a in table_A.AsEnumerable()
                          join b in table_B.AsEnumerable() on a.Field<int>("ID") equals b.Field<int>("ID")
                          select new { a = a, b = b})
                          .GroupBy(x => x.b.Field<string>("CompletedBy"))
                          .ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
----------
Select a.ID, a.Activity, b.CompletedBy
FROM ActivityList a
Right OUTER JOIN ActivityLog b
ON a.ID = b.ActivityID
Where CompletedBy = 'john@auto.com'
GROUP BY a.ID, a.Activity, b.CompletedBy
```

Comment: @ L.F. I have changed left to right join but don’t know what happened

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct just change the potion of condition.

```
Select a.ID, a.Activity, b.CompletedBy
FROM ActivityList a
LEFT JOIN ActivityLog b
ON a.ID = b.ActivityID AND b.CompletedBy = 'john@auto.com' 
GROUP BY a.ID, a.Activity, b.CompletedBy
```